# jquery setting value of textbox not working with '*'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox with the value being updated via jquery and ajax. The value being retrieved will sometimes have an * in it. When the value has the * in it, nothing is being put in the textbox. When I debug it, it shows that it retrieved the correct value, so I know that part is working correctly. How can I tell jquery to put in the exact string? For example, the result might be 216.* and I need that in the textbox. Thanks for your help.

Here is my code

```
  $("#DiagnosisName").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Provider/SearchDiagnosis/",
            data: {
                SearchTerm: request.term
            },
            complete: function (data) {
                    response(data.responseJSON);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 3,

    open: function () {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
    },
    close: function () {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {

        $("#DiagnosisName").val(ui.item.DiagnosisName);
        $("#DiagnosisName").focus();
        $("#DiagnosisDescription").val(ui.item.DiagnosisDescription);
        $("#DiagnosisCode").val(ui.item.DiagnosisCode);
        return false;
    }
})
.autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li>")
      .append("<span>" + item.DiagnosisName + "</span>")
      .appendTo(ul);
};
```

It works fine when the diagnosiscode retrieved via the ajax post does not contain a *. When it does, the DiagnosisCode textbox is blank and everything else is filled in.

Comment: Please post your code in the question.

Comment: Is this where you are putting the value? `<textarea>value goes here</textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><title>Textarea</title>
</head><body><div id="contents">
<textarea id="txt">value goes here</textarea>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = 'new * value';
//]]></script></body></html>
```